# Run IntelliJ IDEA code coverage in command line

Tags: intellij-idea, code-coverage

Is there some ways to run IntelliJ IDEA code coverage in command line?

I need this to run code coverage for Kotlin as job in Jenkins.

Comment: TeamCity CI [supports it](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+Java+Code+Coverage), no docs for running it standalone, though.

Comment: any update on this? were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

We plan to add Maven and Gradle plugins for this, at the moment there is no documentation for running IntelliJ IDEA code coverage from the command line.

TeamCity [supports it out of the box](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Code+Coverage), though.

Comment: Is there still no support for this?

Comment: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-coverage/blob/master/HOWTORUN.md